# Clickable elements in Vuforia not working in iOS

Tags: android, ios, vuforia

I try to project target’s coordinates to screen’s coordinates. I use the same code for iOS and Android:

iOS: http://pastebin.com/rwNZMkqE

Android: http://pastebin.com/rVukMvkN

Android works like a charm, but iOS does not work.

I recorded 2 videos where you can see behavior on Android https://youtu.be/PFSOEClWj2Q and iOS https://youtu.be/zlbyhW2bOGA

Thank you.